# Data factory create hdinsight on-demand cluster fails

Tags: azure, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-factory

I have come upon two major issues trying to make my datafactory implementation work.

This is the first error message i received:

```
Failed to create cluster. HttpCode:PreClusterCreationValidationFailure, Error message: Pre cluster creation validation failed for cluster d4755ccc6-e9d5-4ad3-922e-225a3a2911ff due to user error. Validation Report: HdInsight supports only general-purpose storage accounts with standard tier. Make sure that the account is not a premium or blob only storage account. Information about various storage accounts can be found at go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=808302 Exception: An exception has occurred: The remote server returned an error: (501) Not Implemented.
```

This error returned over and over again, but today I got a new error:

```
Unknown error in module: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentException: 'authority' Uri should have at least one segment in the path (i.e. https //<host>/<path>/...) Parameter name: authority
```

So my question is what is really going on here? All these errors I have found in the Data factory Monitor.

Regards

Erik

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first error check out this question:

[How to create Azure on demand HD insight Spark cluster using Data Factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43545182/how-to-create-azure-on-demand-hd-insight-spark-cluster-using-data-factory)

Not sure about your second error.

Comment: I read the question you referenced but as far as I could understand it was related to Spark. I am trying to run a custom activity I've written in c# on the cluster. Do you mean that custom acitivities suffers from the same limitations as Spark?